# Angular RouteReuseStrategy shouldReuseRoute methods future parameter doesn't provide the actual url

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm facing the problem that the actual url isn't provided through the `future` parameter of the `shouldReuseRoute` method in my custom implementation of [`RouteReuseStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy). The url property has the last url not the actual one. The private property `_routerState` of the future parameter has the right new one in its property url. Does anyone know any further on this or did I get something totally wrong ? Thanks for your help!

```
export class RoutingStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
 ...
   shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
     console.log(future);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActivatedRouteSnapshot.url` only contains the part of the URL that matched the route. I.e. if you have routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'xxx',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'yyy/:id',
            ...
```

and navigate to /xxx/yyy/3 then `ActivatedRouteSnapshot.url` for the innermost route will be an array containing `UrlSegment` objects for 'yyy' and '3'.

You can get the complete URL from `ActivatedRouteSnapshot.pathFromRoot`, which contains the snapshots of all routes leading up to this. From these you could construct the string URL for example like this:

```
export class RoutingStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
 ...
 shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    const url = future.pathFromRoot.map(p => p.url.map(segment => segment.path)).flat().join("/");
    console.log(url);
  }
}
```